# Mocking return type for an external function in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking

Suppose we have the following Python function:

```
def lookup_current_prices_dict(stocks):
    prices = {}

    for stock in stocks:
        prices[stock] = stock_price_toolkit.get_current_price(stock)

    return prices
```

I want to write a unit test for this function, but I don't want to depend on the prices looked up using the `stock_price_toolkit` module. In effect, I want to tell `stock_price_toolkit` to always return `1.00` when `get_current_price()` is called so that I can just test the rest of the function.

I know that this can be done using mock, but I couldn't find any good documentation on how to accomplish this specific task.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `mock.patch`, something like this:

```
with patch('sock_price_toolkit.get_current_price') as m:
    m.return_value = '1.00'
    prices = lookup_current_prices_dict(stocks)
```

Check the oficial [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`mock.patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch), and set [`return_value`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.return_value) of the mock object returned:

```
import stock_price_toolkit

def lookup_current_prices_dict(stocks):
    prices = {}

    for stock in stocks:
        prices[stock] = stock_price_toolkit.get_current_price(stock)

    return prices

#####

import mock
# from unittest import mock  # If you're using Python 3.x
with mock.patch('stock_price_toolkit.get_current_price') as m:
    m.return_value = 1.0
    assert lookup_current_prices_dict(['stock1', 'stock2']) == {
        'stock1': 1.0, 'stock2': 1.0
    }
```

or, you can specify `return_value` as a keyword argument of the `mock.patch`:

```
with mock.patch('stock_price_toolkit.get_current_price', return_value=1.0) as m:
    assert lookup_current_prices_dict(['stock1', 'stock2']) == {
        'stock1': 1.0, 'stock2': 1.0
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact method will depend slightly on which testing module you're using, but this should point you in the right direction:

```
try:
    from unittest import mock  # Python 3
except ImportError:
    import mock  # Third-party module in Python 2


with mock.patch('stock_price_toolkit.get_current_price') as mock_price:
    mock_price.return_value = 1.0
    expected = {'STOC': 1.0, 'STOK': 1.0}
    assert lookup_current_prices(['STOC', 'STOK']) == expected
```